# Can I control creation of behaviors?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Is it possible in WPF and Caliburn.Micro to control the creation of a [System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior.Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) that I've bound in my view?

I have a situation where I want to inject a dependency via the `Caliburn.Micro Bootstrapper` to one of my custom behaviors, but I really don't want resort to some kind of service locator.

My view looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Output">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:ScrollBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class ScrollBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private readonly IMyExteneralDependency _externalDependency;

    public ScrollBehavior(IMyExteneralDependency externalDependency)
    {
        _externalDependency = externalDependency;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged += this.OnTextChanging;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= this.OnTextChanging;
    }

    private void OnTextChanging(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, WPF is the one in charge of the creation of the class in this scenario.  As such, there isn't a direct way to use constructor injection or other similar techniques.

As such, a service locator is a common means of handling this type of scenario.  Silverlight even went as far as including MEF's [`CompositionInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.compositioninitializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for this exact type of scenario, but it was never included in WPF.  I blogged a [port for WPF](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/26/mef-compositioninitializer-for-wpf/) that could be used in this type of scenario.

Comment: Too bad. I wanted to avoid a service locator, but it seems like I don't have a choice. Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: @Patrik Yeah, the problem is that you're not controlling the instantiation - it happens in the internals of WPF, so there's no way to inject correctly otherwise :(

Answer (score 0):

Try modify .ctor like this:

```
    public ScrollBehavior()
    {
        _externalDependency = IoC.Get<IMyExteneralDependency>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is exactly what I don't want to do. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may do not use ServiceLocator but use DependencyProperty instead.
For example, UserControl containing TextBlock can declare dep. property with Inherits enabled, so in your behavior you can easily assign it.
Also, why dont you want to create property IMyExteneralDependency {get;set;} and assign it in the xaml? It will come from your control constructor.